# How to make a star or a cross using an svg ellipse?

Tags: css, svg, ellipse

I am creating an `ellipse` in `svg`. In this `ellipse` I am trying to give a shape like a star or cross. I can not use anything else other than `ellipse`. This is what I have done so far.

```
<ellipse cx="96" cy="126" rx="5" ry="5" fill="#EF4444" stroke="#EF4444" stroke-width="19" stroke-dasharray="4" opacity="1" transform="translate(139 50)"></ellipse>
```

All I did is, added the `stroke-dasharray="4"` and it became like a cross. But it is not proper yet. Can anyone help me on this please.

This is how it looks like now. Which is not a star or a cross.

[image]

Comment: I suppose you could apply a clipPath in the shape of a star or cross to the ellipse.

Comment: Can you please give some more details. I don't have much idea in clipPath

Comment: If you don't know how to create SVG, best use an SVG editor such ask inkscape and use it to draw whatever you need.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am checking now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you mean by

> I can not use anything else other than ellipse

If you strictly follow that restriction, then your request would seem close to impossible.

Your first attempt is a nice idea, but unfortunately it may have issues.  Creating circles or ellipses with stroke widths that are greater than the radius (technically, more than double the radius), can not always be trusted to render correctly.

---

The approach that Robert suggested is better and more flexible, but will require the use of SVG elements other than `<ellipse>`

For example take the following design.

```css
svg {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 70">
  <ellipse cx="50" cy="35" rx="40" ry="28"
           fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>

  <g class="cross">
    <rect x="0" y="20" width="100" height="30" transform="rotate(35, 50,35)"/>
    <rect x="0" y="20" width="100" height="30" transform="rotate(-35, 50,35)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

If we turn the ellipse into a clip path, and apply it to the cross, we get this:

```css
svg {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 70">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="oval">
      <ellipse cx="50" cy="35" rx="40" ry="28"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>

  <g class="cross" clip-path="url(#oval)">
    <rect x="0" y="20" width="100" height="30" transform="rotate(35, 50,35)"/>
    <rect x="0" y="20" width="100" height="30" transform="rotate(-35, 50,35)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

You can make the cross part look however you like, and still clip it with the ellipse.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborative explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Another idea. Cut a cross from a circle using four ellipses

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >  
         
 <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="100" fill="crimson" /> 
 <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="40" fill="none" stroke="black" /> 
 <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="2" fill="black" /> 
 <polyline fill="none"  stroke="black" points="0,0 400,400" />
   <polyline fill="none"  stroke="black" points="0,400 400,0" />
 <ellipse transform="rotate(45 100 125)" cx="80" cy="107" rx="102" ry="50" fill="gold" opacity="0.5" />
   <ellipse transform="translate(125 -20) rotate(135 100 125)" cx="45" cy="80" rx="100" ry="50" fill="gold" opacity="0.5" /> 
     <ellipse transform="translate(125 -20) rotate(225 100 125)" cx="-90" cy="40" rx="100" ry="50" fill="gold" opacity="0.5" /> 
       <ellipse transform="translate(125 -20) rotate(315 100 125)" cx="-125" cy="175" rx="100" ry="50" fill="gold" opacity="0.5" />

</svg>
```

Then you can use these ellipses as a mask.

```css
.container {
width:75vw;
height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 50 400 400"  preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  
<defs>
<mask id="msk"> 
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
  <g id="group" fill="black">
 <ellipse transform="rotate(45 100 125)" cx="80" cy="107" rx="102" ry="50"  />
   <ellipse transform="translate(125 -20) rotate(135 100 125)" cx="45" cy="80" rx="100" ry="50"  /> 
     <ellipse transform="translate(125 -20) rotate(225 100 125)" cx="-90" cy="40" rx="100" ry="50"  /> 
       <ellipse transform="translate(125 -20) rotate(315 100 125)" cx="-125" cy="175" rx="100" ry="50"  />
 </g>
</mask> 
</defs>  
  <image href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fc/Foro_Romano.jpg/1200px-Foro_Romano.jpg "
width="100%" height="100%"  />
 <circle mask="url(#msk)" cx="200" cy="200" r="100" fill="crimson" opacity="0.7" /> 

</svg> 
</div>
```